# Dynamic binding a few

Tags: c++, dynamic-binding

Hi Experts can I do dynamic binding like this.
objshapes is the parent class  called Shape and Rectangle is the child class. I have  a few child classes so depending which shape the user selects, I need to bind the correct shape to the objShapes. So i thought i can bind like this. but i getting an error.

```
 Shape *objShapes[3];    
 objshapes[size]= &new Rectangle(3,lvaule,5)  

 //error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

Hope someone can assist. Thanks

IS THIS CORRECT

```
  objshapes[size]= new Rectangle(3,lvaule,5)
```

Comment: Please post the declaration of `objshapes`.

Comment: @Robᵩ Have added the declaration

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamic binding". There is no binding going on in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ```
> > Shape *objShapes[3];
> > ```

This declares objshapes as an array of 3 pointers-to-Shape.

> > ```
> > objshapes[size]= &new Rectangle(3,lvaule,5)
> > ```

This is non-sensical.

> > IS THIS CORRECT
> >
> > ```
> > objshapes[size]= new Rectangle(3,lvaule,5)
> > ```

Yes<sup>1</sup>, that is correct. `new` returns a pointer-to-Rectangle, which can be stored in a variable of type pointer-to-Shape. Since `objshapes` is an array of pointers-to-Shape. `objshapes[size]` is pointer-to-Shape -- which can accept a pointer-to-Rectangle.

<sup>1. Assuming that `size` is convertable to an integral type, and has the value `0`, `1`, or `2`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You would need an array or container of pointers, or preferably [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), to the base class. For example:

```
std::vector<Shape*> objshapes;
objshapes.push_back(new Rectangle(3,lvaule,5));
objshapes.push_back(new Circle( args));
```

If you are using raw pointers instead of using smart pointers, you have to make sure to de-allocate the memory used by the shapes by calling `delete` on all the pointers.

*Edit* since you are reluctant to use standard library containers, and you have clarified that you have an array of `Shape*`, as opposed to an array of `Shape`, then you can populate the array thus:

```
objshapes[idx]= new Rectangle(3,lvaule,5);
```

Comment: I have edited my question with an answer is this correct.

Comment: @rasul1719435 Then use another container type or an array.

Comment: @rasul1719435 your question suggests that `objshapes` holds `Shapes`, which isn't compatible with your answer.